INTENTAR PUBLICAR EN FACEBOOK CON LA API GRAHP
estoy aprendiendo a usar la api de facebook y estoy haciendo una prueba para hacer una publicacion con python pero me sale este error:

Error al realizar la publicaci�n: 403 {"error":{"message":"(#200) If
posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and
\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or
both pages_read_engagement \\n          and pages_manage_posts
permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\n
requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin
with \\n          sufficient administrative
permission","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"AKtCynS23CixGyDy39fbIUS"}}


El mensaje de error es bastante claro. ¿En qué topas?

Agrega más información de como tratas de realizar la publicación. Revisar [ask], saludos
